# SDWebImage throws an error when setting the image from the url mentioned

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

When I try to set the image from the following url using `SDWebImage` I am getting the following error :-

> URL :-
>   https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/quickride1/1563967975923.png 
>   Error
>   :- Error Domain=SDWebImageErrorDomain Code=2001 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={SDWebImageErrorDownloadStatusCodeKey=404}

Have no idea why the issue is popping up. Any solution Thanks in advance

Have gone through several tutorials on sdwebimage and documentation but none of them address my issue

```
public func setImageToView(imageView : UIImageView, imageUrl : String?,gender : String){
    AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().log.debug("setImageToView() \(gender)")
    if imageUrl == nil || imageUrl?.isEmpty == true || QRSessionManager.getInstance()?.getUserId() == nil || QRSessionManager.getInstance()?.getUserId().isEmpty == true {
        imageView.image = getDefaultUserImage(gender: gender)
        return
    }

    let URL = NSURL(string: imageUrl!)
    if URL == nil
    {
        imageView.image = getDefaultUserImage(gender: gender)
        return
    }
    imageView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL! as URL, placeholderImage: nil , options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0)) { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
        AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().log.debug("Image :- \(image),error :- \(error),cacheType :- \(cacheType),url :- \(url)")
        if error != nil{
            imageView.image = self.getDefaultUserImage(gender: gender)
            return
        }
         self.checkAndSetCircularImage(imageView: imageView, image: image)
     }

}
```

Comment: This code shouldn't compile, is it the same code you have tried?

Comment: @Kamran code is updated

Comment: Try `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.checkAndSetCircularImage(imageView: imageView, image: image) }`

Comment: @Kamran the issue is not with the method self.checkAndSetCircularImage(imageView: imageView, image: image)

Comment: @Kamran The issue is with fetching the image from library. Its not returning the image with the method :- imageView.sd_setImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried your code and everything works fine :

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let imgURL = "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/quickride1/1563967975923.png"

    setImageToView(imageView : imageView, imageUrl : imgURL,gender : "Male")
}

public func setImageToView(imageView : UIImageView, imageUrl : String?,gender : String){

    let URL = NSURL(string: imageUrl!)

    imageView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL! as URL, placeholderImage: nil , options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0)) { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }

}
```

The error message consists in two infos:

1) `SDWebImageErrorDomain Code=2001`, which `SDWebImageError.h` file says:

```swift
SDWebImageErrorInvalidDownloadStatusCode = 2001, 
// The image downloda response a invalid status code. You can check the status code in error's userInfo under `SDWebImageErrorDownloadStatusCodeKey`
```

2) `UserInfo={SDWebImageErrorDownloadStatusCodeKey=404}`:

Apparently a [Not Found error](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

So it appears your device / simulator just isn't reaching the image.

When exactly does this happen? Are you sure you aren't calling this method multiple times or with malformed image URLs?

EDIT

`imageView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()` before calling the method again solved the problem

Comment: Try using imageView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad() before calling the method again

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your problem, I checked the link, everything works like a charm, here is my code

```
guard
        let url = URL(string: "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/quickride1/1563967975923.png")
        else {
            return
    }
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: url) { (image, error, cacheTRype, url) in
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "no error loading image")
    }
```

Comment: This part of code is not loading image but when I go to a different controller and come back its showing  up the image but if I stay in the same page after capturing the image and try to save its not updating the image. its taking time to load

Comment: You mean, you have to wait and then update imageView? use completion block, to handle when image is uploaded and then request it

Comment: I have printed the localised description it is showing the error as " The operation could not be completed"

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem and after looking it turns out that I'm trying to reach for a webImage with a URL that is not valid to my app particularly.

This happened when I tried to fetch an Image URL from firebase storage which turned out It's the wrong storage.